# Efficiently replace multi-line list strings with single_line list string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse output from OS X's `mdls` command. For some keys, the value is a list of values. I need to capture these key, value pairs correctly. All lists of values start with a `(` and then end with a `)`.

I need to be able to iterate over all the key, value pairs so that I can properly parse multiple outputs (i.e. `mdls` run on multiple files to produce a single output, where there is no distinction between where one file's metadata ends and the other's begins). I have some sample code below.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
import re

mdls_output = """kMDItemAuthors                 = (
    margheim
)
kMDItemContentCreationDate     = 2015-07-10 14:41:01 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate = 2015-07-10 14:41:01 +0000
kMDItemContentType             = "com.adobe.pdf"
kMDItemContentTypeTree         = (
    "com.adobe.pdf",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.composite-content",
    "public.content"
)
kMDItemCreator                 = "Safari"
kMDItemDateAdded               = 2015-07-10 14:41:01 +0000
"""

mdls_lists = re.findall(r"^\w+\s+=\s\(\n.*?\n\)$", mdls_output, re.S | re.M)
single_line_lists = [re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', x.strip()) for x in mdls_lists]
for i, mdls_list in enumerate(mdls_lists):
    mdls_output = mdls_output.replace(mdls_list, single_line_lists[i])
print(mdls_output)
```

Comment: Does your solution work?  Are you asking for a memory efficient alternative or a solution that is *faster*?

Comment: It works, but it feels unnecessarily complex. I *want* to nest two `re.sub`s, but I couldn't get that to work; that is, substitute the multiline list for a single-line list, which would require normalizing the whitespace (e.g. `re.sub(r"^\w+\s+=\s\(\n.*?\n\)$", re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', '\1'.strip(), mdls_output)`)

Comment: It mostly looks ok, but your main regex is a little wrong. Probably should be `"^\w+\s*=\s*\(\n.*?\n\)$"`. Shouldn't that be `mdls_output = mdls_output.replace(mdls_list[i], single_line_lists[i])` ?

Comment: Good point on the spaces in the regex. The other point is just a misreading. I iterate over *mdls_lists* and each item is named *mdls_list*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of python's regex **substitute which can take
a function as replacement string**. The function is called for each match with the match object. The returned string replaces the match.

```
def myfn(m):
    return re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', m.group().strip())

pat = re.compile(r"^\w+\s+=\s\(\n.*?\n\)$", re.S | re.M)
mdls_output = pat.sub(myfn, mdls_output)
```

Comment: I *knew* there must be a way to pass a function. I read thru the `re` docs, but most have missed this. Thanks.